# IE and local file reading

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, fileapi

I've just watched the mozilla File API file reading as

```
new FileReader();
```

etc. and I must ask is there something like that for IE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use [ActiveX' FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However, an confirmation box is shown to the user everytime he runs the code. Some users might not trust you and could choose not to run the ActiveX control.
Also, please note that some users also use non-IE browsers which don't support FileReader (Safari, older versions of Firefox and so on). By adding ActiveX, you still won't have 100% support for file-related APIs.

Comment: Does FF support ActiveX FileSystemObject?

Comment: @user592704 Nope. ActiveX is only supported in browsers based on Trident layout engine. You can do simple feature detection to focus on both Internet Explorer and browsers supporting File API.

Comment: OK, I remember that. Thanks :) But How to make IE never show the warning the FileSystemObject is activated? Is there some way out?

Comment: @user592704 No way. IIRC users can disable the warnings in their settings, but you as a web developer have no ability to do that.

Answer (score 8):

Internet Explorer 10 also supports the [FileReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function(){
    // do something with this.result
}
reader.readAsText(readFile);
```

For managed compatability tables regarding the FileReader, be sure to check out [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader).

If you wanted to provide a fall-back for those who may not be visiting your site in Internet Explorer 10, I would encourage you to do a bit of feature-detection to determine whether or not you want to use the FileReader:

```
if ( window.FileReader ) {
    /* Use the FileReader */
} else {
    /* Do something else */ 
}
```

Note also that using an ActiveXObject approach isn't necessarily going to work all the time either as some users browse with [ActiveX Filtering](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/browser/activexfiltering/About.html) enabled, meaning you can't touch their file-system, or run any types of plugins in their browser.