# Javascript Read a local Text File

Tags: javascript, filereader

I am trying to find a way where I can read a local text file using java script. am aware of file reader API however I want to do this in IE7 and the filereader is for IE10 above. Been searching the web and not many good solutions come up? any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Danger: [IE7 (and 8, 9, and 10) have past End of Support](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windowsforbusiness/end-of-ie-support). They do not receive security patches. Do not use them. Upgrade to a supported, secure browser.

Comment: Stop supporting old versions for starters.

Comment: While I agree IE7 should be dead by now, I think the folks telling you "don't use IE7" are providing no help. Sometimes business requirements dictate things you don't agree with yourself... Anyway, it can be done through ActiveX http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710432/ie-and-local-file-reading

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

IE 10 is the first version of IE to support reading local files without plugins.

Answer (score -1):

Add an IE conditional comment to appear in all IE versions less than 10

```
<body>
    <!--[if IE]>
       <h1>Upgrade your browser .... yours is realllllly old</h1> 
       <p>Your browser doesn't support modern features used here</p> 
    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Please tell me how this solves his problem? At least people saying "it can't be done" are responding to his question. I see no where in his question anything saying "How do I disable functionality in IE? By the way your code doesn't even do what you state, it does not have an IE 10 conditional, but an IE conditional. So effectively, you broke his site that works perfectly fine is IE10 and 11.

Comment: @dman2306 IE conditional comment support was dropped in IE10 . This will do nothing in IE 10 and above

Comment: dropped in standards mode yes, not quirks.